# Detect Authentication Type using Client Object Model

Tags: 2010, client-object-model, authentication

Is there a way of detecting the type of authentication used by SharePoint from the client browser?

**Edit** It doesn't have to be via the Client Object Model. If there is a SharePoint JS parameter that tells me this information then even better

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var ctx = new SP.ClientContext();
var user = ctx.get_web().get_currentUser();
ctx.load(user);
ctx.executeQueryAsync(function() {
  var loginName = user.get_loginName();
  console.log(loginName);
});
```

Now you shold be able to see the type in the loginName variable.
I'm not 100% sure, but its worth a try.
For example I get `i:0#.w|somedomain\user` and `i:0#.f|aspnetmembership|otheruser`